# Proper way to handle URLs in the form of http://example.com/

Tags: domains, redirects, url, canonical-url

On an apache server with a standard setup, when I request a URL in the form of:

```
http://127.0.0.1/..
```

I receive this error in my log:

```
[Sun Aug 30 22:52:44 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Invalid URI in request GET /.. HTTP/1.1
```

and HTTP status 400 is returned from apache stating "Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand."

Other servers seem to handle the same type of URL differently.

When I request:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/..
```

I receive an access denied message (server status 403).

When I request one of these:

```
http://google.ca/..
http://google.com/..
```

I receive a temporary redirect to the same URLs without the trailing dots.

I tested everything with CURL.

So my question is what is the **proper** way to handle a request like this?

Comment: Not sure why you are asking. You should no ever see a request like this unless you are being attacked by a hacker.

Comment: I am because I'm configuring my web server to not accept duplicate content and I'm not sure the proper way to handle this request.

Comment: I block these kinds of requests normally. It something akin to cd .. and therefore normally inappropriate. They often come (for me anyway) as a result of trying to gain access to a file by a hacker. If you want to do something with these requests, I would think that just dropping any .. or ../ and seeing if there is any sense in the request at all- if so then show the page, if not then 404 or just 404 right away since you want to be sure there is no duplicate content.

Comment: FWIW the browser itself appears to strip the dots from `/.` and `/..` to make a request for `/`. However, `/...`, `/....` are not touched and requested as is.